# Undefined jQuery after adding no conflict js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magento, undefined

I've added jquery 1.8.2 to both my page.xml file and the corresponding directory.. however i am still getting multiple Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined errors. I have checked to make sure jquery is loaded as well as noconflict.js. I have also disabled the two jquery versions to see if that would make a difference.

[SUBJECT SITE](http://guytgunter.com/shop)

The magento version i am using is ver 1.8.1.0

Jquery no conflict has been added. (no conflict.js gets undefinded error too)

After adding no conflict js i wrote js like this

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
// write your code here
});
```

In the page.xml file the script src is

jquery-1.8.2.min.js
and it is the first script.

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">

    <action method="addJs"><script>jquery-1.8.2.min.js</script></action>

    <action method="addJs"><script>no-conflict.js</script></action>

    <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>

    <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>

    <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
```

ect.

the errors look like this ($j error if after i added $j document function to file) :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $j is not defined guytgunter.com/shop/~/jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined guytgunter.com/shop/~/no-conflict.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined guytgunter.com/shop/~/ddaccordion.js:249
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined guytgunter.com/shop/~/ddaccordion.js:151
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined guytgunter.com/shop/~/jquery.colorbox-min.js:7
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined guytgunter.com/shop/:221
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined guytgunter.com/shop/:283
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined guytgunter.com/shop/:644
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined wecreater.com/web/~/responsiveslides.min.js:170
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined wecreater.com/magento/~/noConflict.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Comment: You're including jQuery **twice**.  The first time, it's your modified version that uses `$j`, but it's imported *before* your "noconflict" file.  None of those other scripts are written to expect "$j" to work as a reference to jQuery.

Comment: The first call to jquery 1.8.2, it starts with `$j(document)` this will not work since your noConflict have not been loaded. The second call to jquery has the correct starting

Comment: @pointy i fixed that problem however i get this error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function `when adding `$j(document).ready(function(){
// write your code here
});`

Comment: @Huangism i have corrected that however i am still getting many errors even when encasing files in  $j(document) function

Comment: @user3756611 you need to call jquery (original file) before doing anything else

Comment: @Huangism I noticed that and it has been fixed. However, i am still getting the same errors

Comment: @user3756611 check your work please, you are still calling jquery after the no conflict

Comment: I don't think you're loading the jQuery library enough times <grin>, maybe add three or four more calls. <script type="text/javascript" src="http://guytgunter.com/shop/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://guytgunter.com/shop/js/ajaxcart/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min-AC.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://guytgunter.com/shop/js/ajaxcart/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Check for the order for js inclucded

2.Check for the jQuery URL loaded properly

3.Check for any other version of jquery used in the website and disable it

This will do the job !!!!

Comment: I have checked your list.

Urls are in correct order. no conflict is first, then i load the jquery library. There are no other js librarys loaded

Comment: I have checked your website. First you need to load jquery library then added noconfict js.But you have used jquery.noConflict() in no-conflict.js first and then loaded Jquery library.That was causing the issue

Answer (score 1):

One simple mistake I've made in the past is to try using jQuery in the Magento head.phtml file.  At this time in the processing cycle the page.xml file won't have been processed and JQuery / noconflict will not be defined even though you'll of course see it when you view source on your page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using $j, then before writing your script add following line within Script tag -

> **$j = jQuery.noConflict();**

Then proceed with $j.

Also make sure you are using Single jQuery library.

You can check this using Browser Short key **Ctrl+U** to see the view-source. With the help of this you can check whether library including once or twice.

Comment: i have added the line before all query and i am using one jquery library 1.8.2

Comment: The jQuery you have included, is in Correct path ? Click on included jQuery after opening view-source. If it shows 404, then please correct the path.